# C++ Repeated do-if-do pattern

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns

I currently have code of the following form:

```
Do1(A);
if (B != null) Do1(B);

Do2(A, true);
if (B != null) Do2(B, true);

Do3(A);
if (B != null) Do3(B);
```

So several times, I execute something for object A, and if B is specified, I also do it for B. This means my entire code is duplicated and I would like to change that but I can't come up with a good way to improve this pattern.

The only idea I had so far was something like

```
auto doBoth = [&A,&B](function<void(const T&)> f) {
  f(A);
  if (B != null) f(B);
};

doBoth(&Do1);
auto do2_bind = [](const T& obj) {Do2(obj, true);};
doBoth(do2_bind);
doBoth(&Do3);
```

but I feel like that would greatly reduce readability and make it harder for someone to understand my code, as there is this quite abstract lambda function and a lot of lambdas in general.

edit: From the answers and comments I see that I should have made some clarifications. I apologize for confusion.

1. A and B are of the same type and are something like Foo* or optional<Foo> which allows a test for null
2. I can only use C++11 features
3. The code blocks (which I abbreviated as DoN here) can be more complex than just a single function call. For example, if might be:

   ```
   Do1(A);
   Do2(A);
   if (B != null) {
     Do1(B);
     Do2(B);
   }
   ```

where the order of operations is important.

Comment: C++17 lambdas with auto-typed parameters ought to make this a lot nicer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That's a C++14 feature.

Comment: Could you do this?

`template <typename X>
void DoAll(X x)
{
Do1(x);
Do2(x, true);
Do3(x);
}
/* ... */
DoAll(a)
if (b) DoAll(b);`
Or do the calls for b depend on side-effects from the calls for a?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach is reasonable, but you don't really seem to need a `std::function`. Just a template that accepts a callable:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename Func>
void do_for_both(A&& a, B&& b, Func&& func)
{
  func(std::forward<A>(a));
  if(b != nullptr)
    func(std::forward<B>(b));
}
```

The above would accept both raw pointers and `optional`s that hold a pointer.
Your calls will then just become:

```
do_for_both(a, b, [](auto&& param){
  Do1(param);
});

do_for_both(a, b, [](auto&& param){
  Do2(param, true);
});
```

---

Well, the above *will* work for c++14. But I now noticed the c++11 requirement. So this answer is now just a reference.

Comment: Agreed. (Although replace "correct" with "reasonable" perhaps - there are no absolutes in what we do!)

Comment: How exactly does this work? `Do1` is two functions: it has an overload for `A` and `B`. How do you pass two functions as one? You ought to get a compile error.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Not according to the code in the question -- both `a` and `b` are type `T`, compatible with passing to `std::function<void (const T&)>`

Comment: @BenVoigt: The code in question makes no sense, as `B` cannot be `nullptr` unless it is a *pointer*. And therefore cannot be passed as `const T&`. Or has a very odd `operator==` overload.

Comment: @NicolBolas - This template does indeed impose the requirement that `A` and `B` are either the same type, or part of the same class hierarchy. But I didn't see anything in the OP's post to suggest it's not the case.

Comment: @NicolBolas: A pointer can be passed as `const T&` if `T` is a pointer type (possibly to a base class).  But yeah, the question doesn't suggest that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I disagree - the question *does* suggest (to me) that A and B are both pointers to the same type.

Comment: @Martin: But then wouldn't you tend to write `const T*&` instead, to show that it's a pointer?  Maybe not, if it could be a smart pointer of unspecified variety.  Still, the question calls `A` an *object* and not a pointer.

Comment: Confusing a pointer and its refererant as a short-cut is common (I often do myself).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and sorry for the confusion. "B == null" was supposed to be pseudocode-ish for a test that B is an invalid object. Also, my blocks can be more complex than just "Do(A, args)", so StoryTeller's solution does not quite work for me, at least not as nicely as it is presented. I still prefer it to mine but it would still bring the issue of having many lambdas. I added an edit to my question which will hopefully clarify my situation.

Comment: As you said, that is not entirely possible in C++11. It still seems like that direction is also the best solution in my case, so I will probably use it. Thanks.